# Is there any non-trivial code that uses Data.Maybe.Is-just?

Tags: agda, option-type

The Agda standard library provides a data type `Maybe` accompanied with a view `Any`.
Then there is the property `Is-just` defined using `Any`. I found working with this type difficult as the standard library provides exactly no tooling for `Any`.

Thus I am looking for examples on how to work with `Is-just` effectively. Is there an open source project that uses it?

Alternatively, I am seeking how to put it to good use:

- Given `Is-just m` and `Is-nothing m`, how to eliminate? Can `Relation.Nullary.Negation.contradiction` be used here?
- Given a property `p : ... → (mp : Is-just m) → ... → ... ≡ to-witness mp` that needs to be shown inductively by `p ... = {! p ... (subst Is-just m≡somethingelse mp) ... !}`, the given term does not fill the hole, because it has type `... ≡ to-witness (subst Is-just m≡somethingelse mp)`.

Often it seems easier to work with `Σ A (_≡_ m ∘ just)` than `Is-just m`.

Comment: Singletons approach `record Is {α} {A : Set α} (x : A) : Set where` looks nicer to me than `Σ A (_≡_ m ∘ just)`: `from-is-just : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} {x : A} -> Is (Maybe.just x) -> A; from-is-just {x = x} _ = x`.

Comment: If there are so many alternatives to `Is-just` that work better, why is the "worst" of all, `Is-just`, part of the standard library?

Comment: I wrote an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31105948/3237465), that elaborates one use case for `Is-just`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, it is possible to derive a contradiction from having both `Is-just m` and `Is-nothing m` in context. You can then use `⊥-elim` to prove anything.

```
module isJust where

open import Level
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Maybe

contradiction :
  {ℓ : Level} {A : Set ℓ} {m : Maybe A}
  (j : Is-just m) (n : Is-nothing m) → ⊥
contradiction (just _) (just pr) = pr
```

The second one is a bit too abstract for me to be sure whether what I'm suggesting will work but the usual strategies are to try to pattern match on the value of type `Maybe A` or on the proof that `Is-just m`.

As for using another definition of `Is-just`, I tend to like

```
open import Data.Bool

isJust : {ℓ : Level} {A : Set ℓ} (m : Maybe A) → Set
isJust m = T (is-just m)
```

because it computes.

Comment: Is there public example code that uses this `isJust` instead?

Comment: Sure. For instance I defined `fromJust` for a similar  `isJust` [here](https://github.com/gallais/agdARGS/blob/master/agdARGS/Data/Maybe.agda) and use it to make smart constructors [there](https://github.com/gallais/agdARGS/blob/master/agdARGS/Data/UniqueSortedList/SmartConstructors.agda#L21)