# Eliminating a Maybe at the type level

Tags: agda, dependent-type

Is there any way to unwrap a value, which is inside the `Maybe` monad, at the type level? For example, how to define type-safe `tail` for `Vec`s having this variant of `pred`:

```
pred : ℕ -> Maybe ℕ
pred  0      = nothing
pred (suc n) = just n
```

? Something like

```
tail : ∀ {n α} {A : Set α} -> Vec A n ->
  if isJust (pred n) then Vec A (from-just (pred n)) else ⊤
```

This example is totally artificial, but it's not always possible to get rid of some precondition, so you can write a correct by construction definition like the `tail` function from the standard library:

```
tail : ∀ {a n} {A : Set a} → Vec A (1 + n) → Vec A n
tail (x ∷ xs) = xs
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## A first attempt

We can define a data type for that:

```
data _>>=ᵗ_ {α β} {A : Set α} : (mx : Maybe A) -> (A -> Set β) -> Set (α ⊔ β) where
  nothingᵗ : ∀ {B}   ->        nothing >>=ᵗ B
  justᵗ    : ∀ {B x} -> B x -> just x  >>=ᵗ B
```

I.e. `mx >>=ᵗ B` is either `B x`, where `just x ≡ mx`, or "nothing". We then can define `tail` for `Vec`s as follows:

```
pred : ℕ -> Maybe ℕ
pred  0      = nothing
pred (suc n) = just n

tailᵗ : ∀ {α n} {A : Set α} -> Vec A n -> pred n >>=ᵗ Vec A 
tailᵗ  []      = nothingᵗ
tailᵗ (x ∷ xs) = justᵗ xs
```

In the `[]` case `n` is `0`, so `pred n` reduces to `nothing`, and `nothingᵗ` is the only value we can return.

In the `x ∷ xs` case `n` is `suc n'`, so `pred n` reduces to `just n'`, and we need to apply the `justᵗ` constructor to a value of type `Vec A n'`, i.e. `xs`.

We can define `from-justᵗ` pretty much like `from-just` is defined in `Data.Maybe.Base`:

```
From-justᵗ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {B : A -> Set β} {mx : Maybe A} -> mx >>=ᵗ B -> Set β
From-justᵗ  nothingᵗ         = Lift ⊤
From-justᵗ (justᵗ {B} {x} y) = B x

from-justᵗ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {B : A -> Set β} {mx : Maybe A} -> (yᵗ : mx >>=ᵗ B) -> From-justᵗ yᵗ
from-justᵗ  nothingᵗ = _
from-justᵗ (justᵗ y) = y
```

Then the actual `tail` function is

```
tail : ∀ {n α} {A : Set α} -> (xs : Vec A n) -> From-justᵗ (tailᵗ xs)
tail = from-justᵗ ∘ tailᵗ
```

Some tests:

```
test-nil : tail (Vec ℕ 0 ∋ []) ≡ lift tt
test-nil = refl

test-cons : tail (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []) ≡ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []
test-cons = refl
```

However we want to be able to map values of type `mx >>=ᵗ B`, so let's try to define a function for that:

```
_<$>ᵗ_ : ∀ {α β γ} {A : Set α} {B : A -> Set β} {C : ∀ {x} -> B x -> Set γ} {mx : Maybe A}
       -> (∀ {x} -> (y : B x) -> C y) -> (yᵗ : mx >>=ᵗ B) -> mx >>=ᵗ λ x -> {!!}
g <$>ᵗ yᵗ = {!!}
```

How to fill the holes? In the first hole we have

```
Goal: Set (_β_86 yᵗ)
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
x  : A
yᵗ : mx >>=ᵗ B
mx : Maybe A
C  : {x = x₁ : A} → B x₁ → Set γ
B  : A → Set β
A  : Set α
```

The equation `just x ≡ mx` should hold, but we can't prove that, so there is no way to turn `yᵗ : mx >>=ᵗ B` into `y : B x` to make it possible to fill the hole with `C y`. We could instead define the type of `_<$>ᵗ_` by pattern matching on `yᵗ`, but then we couldn't map something, that was already mapped, using the same `_<$>ᵗ_`.

## Actual solution

So we need to establish the property, that `mx ≡ just x` in `mx >>=ᵗ λ x -> e`. We can assign `_>>=ᵗ_` this type signature:

```
data _>>=ᵗ_ {α β} {A : Set α} : (mx : Maybe A) -> (∀ {x} -> mx ≡ just x -> Set β) -> Set (α ⊔ β)
```

but all we actually care is that `mx` is `just` in the `justᵗ` case — from this we can recover the `x` part, if needed. Hence the definition:

```
Is-just : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> Maybe A -> Set
Is-just = T ∘ isJust

data _>>=ᵗ_ {α β} {A : Set α} : (mx : Maybe A) -> (Is-just mx -> Set β) -> Set (α ⊔ β) where
  nothingᵗ : ∀ {B}   ->        nothing >>=ᵗ B
  justᵗ    : ∀ {B x} -> B _ -> just x  >>=ᵗ B
```

I don't use `Is-just` from the standard library, because it doesn't compute — it's crucial in this case.

But there is a problem with this definition:

```
tailᵗ : ∀ {α n} {A : Set α} -> Vec A n -> pred n >>=ᵗ λ n' -> {!!}
```

the context in the hole looks like

```
Goal: Set _230
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
n' : Is-just (pred n)
A  : Set α
n  : ℕ
```

`n'` is not a number. It's possible to convert it to a number by pattern matching on `n`, but this is too verbose and ugly. Instead we can incorporate this pattern matching in an auxiliary function:

```
! : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {B : ∀ {mx} -> Is-just mx -> Set β} {mx : Maybe A}
  -> (∀ x {_ : mx ≡ just x} -> B {just x} _) -> (imx : Is-just mx) -> B imx
! {mx = nothing} f ()
! {mx = just x } f _  = f x {refl}
```

`!` makes from a function, that acts on `A`, a function, that acts on `Is-just mx`. The `{_ : mx ≡ just x}` part is not necessary, but it can be useful to have this property.

The definition of `tailᵗ` then is

```
tailᵗ : ∀ {α n} {A : Set α} -> Vec A n -> pred n >>=ᵗ ! λ pn -> Vec A pn
tailᵗ  []      = nothingᵗ
tailᵗ (x ∷ xs) = justᵗ xs
```

`from-justᵗ` is almost the same as before:

```
From-justᵗ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {mx : Maybe A} {B : Is-just mx -> Set β}
           -> mx >>=ᵗ B -> Set β
From-justᵗ  nothingᵗ     = Lift ⊤
From-justᵗ (justᵗ {B} y) = B _

from-justᵗ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {mx : Maybe A} {B : Is-just mx -> Set β}
           -> (yᵗ : mx >>=ᵗ B) -> From-justᵗ yᵗ
from-justᵗ  nothingᵗ = _
from-justᵗ (justᵗ y) = y
```

And `tail` is the same:

```
tail : ∀ {α n} {A : Set α} -> (xs : Vec A n) -> From-justᵗ (tailᵗ xs)
tail = from-justᵗ ∘ tailᵗ
```

Tests pass:

```
test-nil : tail (Vec ℕ 0 ∋ []) ≡ lift tt
test-nil = refl

test-cons : tail (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []) ≡ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []
test-cons = refl
```

However now we can also define a fmap-like function:

```
runᵗ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {mx : Maybe A} {B : Is-just mx -> Set β}
     -> mx >>=ᵗ B -> (imx : Is-just mx) -> B imx
runᵗ {mx = nothing}  _        ()
runᵗ {mx = just  x} (justᵗ y) _  = y

_<$>ᵗ_ : ∀ {α β γ} {A : Set α} {mx : Maybe A} {B : Is-just mx -> Set β} {C : ∀ {x} -> B x -> Set γ}
       -> (∀ {x} -> (y : B x) -> C y) -> (yᵗ : mx >>=ᵗ B) -> mx >>=ᵗ C ∘ runᵗ yᵗ
g <$>ᵗ nothingᵗ = nothingᵗ
g <$>ᵗ justᵗ y  = justᵗ (g y)
```

I.e. having `imx : Is-just mx` we can reduce `mx >>=ᵗ B` to `B imx` using the `runᵗ` function. Applying `C` to the result gives the desired type signature.

Note that in the `just  x` case

```
runᵗ {mx = just  x} (justᵗ y) _  = y
```

`y : B tt`, while `Goal : B imx`. We can treat `B tt` as `B imx` because all inhabitants of `⊤` are indistinguishable, as witnessed by

```
indistinguishable : ∀ (x y : ⊤) -> x ≡ y
indistinguishable _ _ = refl
```

This is due to the eta rule for the `⊤` data type.

Here is the final test:

```
test : from-justᵗ ((0 ∷_) <$>ᵗ ((0 ∷_) <$>ᵗ tailᵗ (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []))) ≡ 0 ∷ 0 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []
test = refl
```

## Remarks

We can also introduce some syntactic sugar:

```
¡ : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {B : A -> Set β} {mx : Maybe A}
  -> (∀ x {_ : mx ≡ just x} -> B x) -> mx >>=ᵗ ! λ x -> B x
¡ {mx = nothing} f = nothingᵗ
¡ {mx = just  x} f = justᵗ (f x {refl})
```

And use it when unification is not needed, like in this example:

```
pred-replicate : ∀ {n} -> pred n >>=ᵗ ! λ pn -> Vec ℕ pn
pred-replicate = ¡ λ pn -> replicate {n = pn} 0
```

`!` alternatively can be defined as

```
is-just : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} {mx} {x : A} -> mx ≡ just x -> Is-just mx
is-just refl = _

!' : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {mx : Maybe A} {B : Is-just mx -> Set β}
   -> (∀ x {p : mx ≡ just x} -> B (is-just p)) -> (imx : Is-just mx) -> B imx
!' {mx = nothing} f ()
!' {mx = just x } f _  = f x {refl}
```

Since `B` now is of type `Is-just mx -> Set β` instead of `∀ {mx} -> Is-just mx -> Set β`, this definition is more inference-friendly, but since there is pattern matching in `is-just`, this definition can probably break some beta equalities.

`¡'` could be defined in this manner as well

```
¡' : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} {mx : Maybe A} {B : Is-just mx -> Set β}
   -> (∀ x {p : mx ≡ just x} -> B (is-just p)) -> mx >>=ᵗ B
¡' {mx = nothing} f = nothingᵗ
¡' {mx = just  x} f = justᵗ (f x {refl})
```

but this definition breaks needed beta equalities:

```
pred-replicate' : ∀ {n} -> pred n >>=ᵗ ! λ pn -> Vec ℕ pn
pred-replicate' = ¡' λ pn {_} -> {!!}
```

The type of the hole is `! (λ pn₁ {._} → Vec ℕ pn₁) (is-just p)` instead of `Vec ℕ pn`.

---

The [code](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/maybe-elim.agda).

---

**EDIT** It turned out that this version is not very usable. I'm using [this](https://github.com/effectfully/STLC/blob/master/src/STLC/Lib/MaybeElim.agda) now:

```
data _>>=ᵀ_ {α β} {A : Set α} : (mx : Maybe A) -> (∀ x -> mx ≡ just x -> Set β) -> Set β where
```