# Getting to terms with Lift and Setω, and variable occurrences in expressions

Tags: types, polymorphism, expression, semantics, agda

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209339/haskell-deriving-mechanism-for-agda), I had types for a toy language

```
data Type : Set where
  Nat  : Type
  Prp : Type
```

I thought about interpreting them by using a disjoint union
`Type → Set ⊎ Set₁`, but thought level lifiting would be best
and was helped to obtain

```
⟦_⟧ₜ : Type → Set₁
⟦ Nat ⟧ₜ = Lift ℕ
⟦ Prp ⟧ₜ = Set
```

Now suppose my toy language has variables and expressions

```
data Variable : Type → Set where
  x y : ∀ {t} → Variable t

data Expr : Type → Set₁ where
  Var : ∀ {t} (v : Variable t) → Expr t      -- varaible symbols
   : ℕ → Expr Nat                         -- constant symbols
   : Set → Expr Prp
  _+_ : (m n : Expr Nat) → Expr Nat          -- binary function symbol
  _≈_ : (e f : Expr Nat) → Expr Prp          -- binary relation symbol
```

Then semantics of expressions,

```
State = ∀ {t} → Variable t → ⟦ t ⟧ₜ

⟦_⟧ₑ : ∀ {t} → Expr t → State → ⟦ t ⟧ₜ
⟦_⟧ₑ (Var v)  σ = σ v
⟦_⟧ₑ ( q)   σ = lift q
⟦_⟧ₑ ( p)   σ = p
⟦_⟧ₑ (e + e₁) σ = lift $ lower (⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ) +ℕ     lower (⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ)
⟦_⟧ₑ (e ≈ e₁) σ = lift (lower (⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ)) ≡ lift (lower (⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ))
```

I kind of get that in-general `lift (lower x) ≠ x` due to 'level refreshing' due to `lift`,
but still why cannot the last line simply be `⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ ≡ ⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ` ?

I must admit that this is my first time using `Lift` and sadly did not find a tutorial/explanation on it ---besides the idea that it embeds small types into large types, as indicated by its definition.

---

Since I've everything laid out, let me make a rather particular query.

With the standard/derived equalities,

```
-- no quick `deriving Eq' mechanism, yet.
postulate _≟ₜ_ : Decidable {A = Type} _≡_   
postulate _≟ᵥ_ : ∀ {t s} → Variable t → Variable s → Bool
```

I can defined textual substitution over expressions,

```
_[_/_] : ∀ {s t} → Expr t → Variable s → Expr s → Expr t
_[_/_] {s} {t} (Var v) u e with s ≟ₜ t
Var v [ u / e ] | yes refl = if v ≟ᵥ u then e else Var v
Var v [ u / e ] | no ¬p = Var v
 n [ v / e ] =  n
 p [ v / e ] =  p
(E + F) [ v / e ] = E [ v / e ] + F [ v / e ]
(E ≈ F) [ v / e ] = E [ v / e ] ≈ F [ v / e ]
```

Now is the issue of variable occurrences within expressions.

```
_not-occurs-in₀_ : ∀ {t} → Variable t → Expr t → Set₁
v not-occurs-in₀ E = ∀ {e} → E [ v / e ] ≡ E

_not-occurs-in₁_ : ∀ {t} → Variable t → Expr t → Set₁
v not-occurs-in₁ E = ∀ {e} {σ : State} → ⟦ E [ v / e ] ⟧ₑ σ ≡ ⟦ E ⟧ₑ σ
```

I've had trouble using either definition.
In particular, I could not even define one in terms of the other.
Any help on this would be appreciated!

---

After [some digging around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863273/modeling-system-fs-parametric-polymorphism-at-set%E2%82%80), I tried

```
levelOf : Type → Level
levelOf Nat = zero
levelOf Prp = suc zero

New⟦_⟧ₜ : (t : Type) → Set (levelOf t)
New⟦ Nat ⟧ₜ = ℕ
New⟦ Prp ⟧ₜ = Set
```

However, now I get `Setω` errors for the definition of `State` above! That is,

```
-- works fine if i use the risky {-# OPTIONS --type-in-type #-}
NState = {t : Type} → Variable t → New⟦ {!t!} ⟧ₜ
```

[As far as I know](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.UniversePolymorphism), such an error occurs, roughly, when one has an assignment of levels to universes.

What shenanigans am I unsconsciously doing to get this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that `Set₁ ∋ Lift ℕ ∋ ⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ` and `Set α ∋ (Set α ∋ A ∋ x) ≡ (Set α ∋ A ∋ y)`, where `_∋_` is from the `Function` module:

```
infixl 0 _∋_
_∋_ : ∀ {a} (A : Set a) → A → A
A ∋ x = x
```

Hence the expression `⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ ≡ ⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ` lies in `Set₁` (because the types of `⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ` and `⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ` lie in `Set₁`), while you need it to be in `Set`. You can either write

```
⟦_⟧ₑ (e ≈ e₁) σ = lower (⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ) ≡ lower (⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ)
```

or redefine `_≡_` making use of a new feature that allows to "force out" levels that appear only in the types of parameters and indices of a data type:

```
data _≡′_ {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : A → Set where
  refl′ : x ≡′ x
```

Note the `Set` instead of `Set a`. Then it's

```
⟦_⟧ₑ (e ≈ e₁) σ = ⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ ≡′ ⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ
```

I'll choose the first option.

---

Your `_not-occurs-inₙ_` are not quite not-occurs, since `e` can be `Var v` and `E [ v / Var v ] ≡ E` regardless of whether `v` occurs in `E` or not. Why not define `_not-occurs-in_` as a data type? BTW, I think it would be more standard to pronounce substitutions either as `E [ v ≔ e ]` or `[ e / v ] E`.

You can go from `_not-occurs-in₀_` to `_not-occurs-in₁_` like this:

```
+-inj : ∀ {E₁ E₂ E₃ E₄} -> E₁ + E₂ ≡ E₃ + E₄ -> E₁ ≡ E₃ × E₂ ≡ E₄ 
+-inj refl = refl , refl

≈-inj : ∀ {E₁ E₂ E₃ E₄} -> E₁ ≈ E₂ ≡ E₃ ≈ E₄ -> E₁ ≡ E₃ × E₂ ≡ E₄ 
≈-inj refl = refl , refl

coe : ∀ {t s} {v : Variable t} → (E : Expr s) → v not-occurs-in₀ E → v not-occurs-in₁ E
coe {t} {v} (Var w)  q {e} rewrite q {e} = refl
coe ( n)  q = refl
coe ( p)  q = refl
coe (E + E₁) q =
  cong₂ (λ n m → lift $ lower n +ℕ lower m) (coe E (proj₁ (+-inj q))) (coe E₁ (proj₂ (+-inj q)))
coe (E ≈ E₁) q =
  cong₂ (λ p₁ p₂ → lower p₁ ≡ lower p₂) (coe E (proj₁ (≈-inj q))) (coe E₁ (proj₂ (≈-inj q)))
```

---

It's not possible to give a name to a type like `∀ α -> Set (f α)` because this type doesn't have a type in Agda as explained in the link you mentioned. But you can transform the expression a little to get a function:

```
F : ∀ α -> Set (suc (f α))
F α = Set (f α)
```

Using the same transformation you can define `NState` and `⟦_⟧ₑ`:

```
NState : ∀ t → Set (levelOf t)
NState t = Variable t → New⟦ t ⟧ₜ

⟦_⟧ₑ : ∀ {t} → Expr t → (∀ {t} -> NState t) → New⟦ t ⟧ₜ
⟦_⟧ₑ (Var v)  σ = σ v
⟦_⟧ₑ ( q)   σ = q
⟦_⟧ₑ ( p)   σ = p
⟦_⟧ₑ (e + e₁) σ = ⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ +ℕ ⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ
⟦_⟧ₑ (e ≈ e₁) σ = ⟦ e ⟧ₑ σ ≡ ⟦ e₁ ⟧ₑ σ
```

Try to go from the current `NState` to your original `NState` to see the issue with the latter: what is the type of `∀ {t} -> NState t`? `Set` applied to what? The type of `NState t` depends on `t`, but when `t` is universally quantified this dependency can't be reflected at the type level.

It would be nice to write

```
syntax (∀ {t} -> NState t) = State
```

but Agda doesn't allow that.

BTW, in theory a universe of universes (i.e. `Setω`) exists: it's a [super universe](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.221.1318&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Though, `Setω` is an unfortunate name for it, because such universe is not a `Set` — it's bigger than any `Set`, because it contains them all. You can found these ideas expressed in Agda [here](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Omega.agda).

[The code](http://lpaste.net/157829).