# Known pattern match in agda

Tags: haskell, agda

Roughly, I have

```
check : UExpr -> Maybe Expr
```

And I have a test term

```
testTerm : UExpr
```

Which I hope will `check` successfully, after which I want to extract the resulting `Expr` and manipulate it further.  Basically

```
realTerm : Expr
just realTerm = check testTerm
```

Such that this definition would fail to typecheck if `check testTerm` turned out to be `nothing`.  Is this possible?

Comment: You might find [Eliminating a Maybe at the type level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105947/eliminating-a-maybe-at-the-type-level) useful.

Comment: In contrast to the technical answers below, I want to point out you're are thinking non-functionally. It's like someone who wants to get rid of the `IO` monad and writes imperative code everywhere in Haskell: generally, there is no way to extract the underlying type from a term of type `Maybe` whatever; It's the gist of strong functional programming languages such as Agda, so you must pass the monad all the way around until you find a good way to encode it into value of another type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual deal is to write something like

```
Just : {X : Set} -> Maybe X -> Set
Just (just x) = One -- or whatever you call the fieldless record type
Just nothing = Zero

justify : {X : Set}(m : Maybe X){p : Just m} -> X
justify (just x) = x
justify nothing {()}
```

If m computes to a success, the type of p is One and the value is inferred.

Comment: I had just started seeing that idiom around with `True` but didn't really dig in. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well I found one way to do it, which is sortof bizarre and magical.

```
testTerm-checks : Σ Expr (\e -> check testTerm ≡ just e)
testTerm-checks = _ , refl

realTerm : Expr
realTerm = proj₁ testTerm-checks
```

This gives me the heebie jeebies, but not necessarily in a bad way.  Still interested in other ways to do it.